# navigation from entity to all it's navigation foreign key objects

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I have an entity which has several foreign keys (int) . 
I want to check if the Foreign Key Objects exists in the DB.
I want to do it as much generic as possible, so i won't need to check for each entity it's navigation properties

Comment: OK, how can we help?

Comment: how can i do it? how can i check in generic way if the Foreign Key object exists in DB